# jquery - checkbox parent onclick if child is checked or unchecked

Tags: jquery, if-statement, checkbox

```
check1 = $('.myCheckBox1');
check1Parent = $('.myBarElems:nth-child(4)');
check1Parent.click(function() {
    if(check1.is(':checked')){
        check1.prop('checked', false);
    }else{
        check1.prop('checked', true);
    }
    alert('clicked');
});
```

when I click on the parent only the alert appears, but the code doesn't work properly:
the checkbox is not checked/unchecked...

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3zQX9/)**

Comment: How about a complete code example? Post the HTML please and a jsFiddle.net example would be helpful.

Comment: Can you try to debug it with debugger tools? And check which part actually goes wrong

Comment: ok i'm preparing a fiddl edemo.. but in the dev tools nothing appears... if i try to alert( check1.prop('checked') ); it returne undefined

Answer (score 0):

I saw the problem in fiddle. You have used **id="myCheckBox1"** on the checkbox HTML but in the **javacript selector** you are using **.myCheckBox1** class to select the element. so the element will be undefined because there is not element in the DOM

Here is the working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3zQX9/1/

```
check1 = $('#myCheckBox1');
check1Parent = $('.myBarElems:nth-child(4)');
check1Parent.click(function() {
  if(check1.is(':checked')){
     check1.prop('checked', false);
  }else{
     check1.prop('checked', true);
  }
  alert('clicked');
});
```